# On the sums $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\frac{i}{n}\ln(\frac{i}{n}) $ and $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\frac{i}{n}\ln(\frac{i}{n}) $

Tags: limits, summation, logarithms

I was thinking about
unimodal sequences,
and the two which
occurred to me are
$\binom{n}{i}$
and
$\dfrac{i}{n}\ln(\dfrac{i}{n})
$,
both for
$i=0$ to $n$
(for the second,
its value is $0$ at $i=0$).

For the first,
it is well known that
$\sum_{i=0}^n 
\binom{n}{i}
=2^n
$
and
$\sum_{i=0}^n 
(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}
=0
$.

I naturally wondered about
the corresponding results for
$A_n
=\sum_{i=0}^n\dfrac{i}{n}\ln(\dfrac{i}{n})
$
and
$A_n^{\pm}
=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\dfrac{i}{n}\ln(\dfrac{i}{n})
$.

Here's what I have shown.

$$A_n
= -\dfrac{n}{4}+\dfrac{\ln(n)}{12n}+\dfrac1{4n}+O\left(\dfrac1{n^2}\right)
$$
$$A_{2n}^{\pm}
=\dfrac{3\ln(n)}{8n}+O\left(\dfrac1{n}\right)
$$
$$A_{2n+1}^{\pm}
=\dfrac{\ln(n)}{8n}+O\left(\dfrac1{n}\right)
$$

I have verified these computationally.

My proofs,
as they often are,
are fairly messy,
especially for
$A_{n}^{\pm}
$,
so my questions are
(ya gotta have a question)

1. How well known are these results?
2. Are there reasonably simple proofs of them?
3. Is there a simple proof that $A_{n}^{\pm}
   \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: are you sure your sums start at $i=0$?

Comment: You can start them at 1 if it makes you feel better. I consider them a discrete version (for $A_n$) of $\int_0^1 x\ln(x) dx$, so the terms are zero at $i=0$.

Comment: The convention $0\log 0=0$ is often used.

Comment: For the first one, if started from $i=1$, the Mathematica gives a longish expression in terms of Zeta and Log(Glaisher)!

Answer (score 1):

As @Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc commented

$$A_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\log \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)=\frac{12 \zeta ^{(1,0)}(-1,n+1)+12 \log (A)-6 n(n+1) \log \left({n}\right)-1}{12 n}$$

For large values of $n$
$$A_n=-\frac{n}{4}+\frac{12\log (A)+ \log
   \left({n}\right)}{12n}+\frac{1}{720 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

Computing $A_n+\frac{n}{4}$ with $n=10^k$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 0.044065045700551029177 & 0.044065043726241327229 \\
 2 & 0.006325187980883474321 & 0.006325187980863634043 \\
 3 & 0.000824400751671184572 & 0.000824400751671184374 \\
 4 & 0.000101628284137902171 & 0.000101628284137902171 \\
 5 & 0.000012081649324481089 & 0.000012081649324481089
\end{array}
\right)$$

We also have
$$\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}=1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{24 \log (A)+2 \log (n)-1}{3 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Comment: I found my error - my 6n should be 12n as shown here. My 1/n term still differs, but I don't want to chase that down.

Comment: @martycohen. No problem with the $\frac 1n$ term since $\log(A)=0.248754\sim \frac 14$ !!

Comment: But that's for small values of $\frac14$.

Comment: Also see this related question of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510666/a-conjecture-on-alternating-sums-of-unimodal-sequences